# Knockout and prototype does not works properly

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have some proplem with inheritance in knockoutjs. I get the next result

> - name1 (id1)
>
>   - name6 (id6)
>   - name6 (id6)
>   - name6 (id6)
>
>     - name6 (id6)
>     - name6    (id6)

```
<ul>
    <li data-bind="text: name() + ' (' + id() + ')'"></li>
    <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'nodeTree', foreach: nodes }">
    </ul>
</ul>
<script type="text/html" id="nodeTree">
    <li data-bind="text: name() + ' (' + id() + ')'"></li>
    <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'nodeTree', foreach: nodes }">
    </ul>
</script>
<script>
    var TreeNode = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.id = ko.observable();
        self.name = ko.observable();
        self.nodes = ko.observableArray();
    }

    var RootNode = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.id(dataModel.id);
        self.name(dataModel.name);
        self.nodes = ko.computed(function () {
            return DataToArray(dataModel.component);
        });
    }

    var ComponentNode = function (data) {
        var self = this;
        var that = new TreeNode();
        if (data !== null) {
            that.id(data.id);
            that.name(data.name);
            if (data.component && data.component.length > 0)
                that.nodes = DataToArray(data.component);
        }
    }
    ComponentNode.prototype = new TreeNode();
    RootNode.prototype = new TreeNode();

    function DataToArray(mass) {
        var arr = [];
        if (mass !== null) for (var i = 0; i < mass.length; i++) {
            var obj = new ComponentNode(mass[i]);
            arr.push(obj);
        }
        return arr;
    }

    var dataModel = {
        id: "id1",
        name: "name1",
        component: [{
            id: "id2",
            name: "name2",
            component: []
        }, {
            id: "id3",
            name: "name3",
            component: []
        }, {
            id: "id4",
            name: "name4",
            component: [{
                id: "id5",
                name: "name5",
                component: []
            }, {
                id: "id6",
                name: "name6",
                component: []
            }]
        }]
    };

    ko.applyBindings(new RootNode());
</script>
```

I'm not understand why when properties **id** and **name** are not observable all works fine.
See http://jsfiddle.net/Ly81tbr4/7/

Comment: Hmm, seems if remove lines with assignment prototype and add line **ko.utils.extend(self, new TreeNode());** in both constructors **RootNode** and **ComponentNode** all works fine, but I need do some tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to be making your observables as part of the prototype. Doing so makes the observable instances shared across all instances of your objects. The observables *must* be unique per instance.

Rather than adding the observables to the prototype, just call the parent constructor within your child constructors.

```
var TreeNode = function () {
    this.id = ko.observable();
    this.name = ko.observable();
    this.nodes = ko.observableArray();
}

var RootNode = function (model) {
    TreeNode.call(this);
    ...
}
var ComponentNode = function (data) {
    TreeNode.call(this);
    ...
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeff1203/Ly81tbr4/10/)